# Py2app: A main script could not be located in the Resources folder

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, py2app

I am building a GUI tkinter python3 application and attempting to compile it with py2app. For some reason when I try to launch the .app bundle in the dist folder it gives me this error:
*A main script could not be located in the Resources folder*
I was wondering why it is doing this, as it is rather frustrating, and I can not find anything about it anywhere. I copied my .py file into the resources folder (Networking.py). Previous to this error I also found an error in the Info.plist. In the key where it states the runtime executable, I found it was trying to get python2.7, which I have updated and am no longer using. I changed it to my current version, which the path for looks like this:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Python
It may be worth noting that it had a strange path previously, which did not look like a proper path to me. It was 
@executable_path/../Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
I removed this completely... Was this wrong? I have no idea about anything about XML, which is what it seemed to be...

Also when compiling this happened:
error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/Users/Ember/dist/Networking.app/Contents/MacOS/Networking'

Any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks!

**EDIT**

I actually figured out: a bit of a stupid mistake, but since I'm using python 3.x I have to type in python3 before doing it.

Answer (score 0):

In your "setup.py" file that you used to create the application, did you remember to list all the modules used in your code. For example, if you used the OS and Glob modules, then you would add this to your setup.py next to "OPTIONS":

```
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True, 'includes':['glob', 'os']}
```

Basically, anything that you import into your module, you should include in the setup.py. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Furthermore, try running it with python3 if that's what you're using, for example, when building the alias version of the application, put: $ python3 setup.py py2app -A

Comment: yep, see answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured out: a bit of a stupid mistake, but since I'm using python 3.x I have to type in `python3` before doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

```
python setup.py py2app
```

I tried

```
python3 setup.py py2app
```

and it worked just fine. Hope this helps.